# Proving $σ_{ji,j} + f_i = ρ(Dv_i/Dt) \implies (σ_{ij} - ρv_iv_j) + f_i = \partial(ρv_i)/ \partial t$

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors, fluid-dynamics

**Exercise :**

> Prove that
>   $$σ_{ji,j} + f_i = ρ(Dv_i/Dt) \implies (σ_{ij} - ρv_iv_j)_{,j} + f_i = \partial(ρv_i)/ \partial t$$
>   where $σ_{ij} = σ_{ji}$ is the stress tensor.

**Attempt :**

It is :

$$\frac{Dv_i}{Dt} = \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t} + v_j\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}$$

Thus, we yield :

$$σ_{ji,j} + f_i = ρ\bigg(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t} + v_j\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\bigg) \Rightarrow σ_{ji,j} + f_i -ρv_j\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} = ρ\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t}$$

$$\implies$$

$$\dots$$

How does one continue and use the Continuity Equation to yield the desired expression ? It starts to form since the inded $,j$ means the differential with respect to $j$ coordinate variable and we have aspects of that there, but I cannot finalise it.

Comment: It should be
$$\frac{Dv_i}{Dt} = \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t} + v_j \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}$$

Comment: @md2perpe Hey thanks a lot for your reply ! Why would it be $v_j$ ? I see there's my mistake but can you clarify so I can understand ?

Comment: The material derivative is 
$$\frac{D}{Dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + v \cdot \nabla$$
Here, 
$$v \cdot \nabla = v_j \partial_j = v_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$$
Thus,
$$\frac{D v_i}{Dt} = \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t} + v_j  \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}$$

Comment: @md2perpe Nice and smooth ! And then, combining them into a whole expression, I get it why $σ_{ij,j} = σ_{ji,j}$ and the other differential as well, but how does $v_j$ sticks in there while the index $,j$ is out there as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
$$\begin{align}
\rho \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t}
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \rho v_i \right) - \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} v_i \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \rho v_i \right) - \left( \nabla \cdot (\rho v) \right) v_i \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \rho v_i \right) - \left( \partial_j (\rho v_j) \right) v_i \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \rho v_i \right) - \partial_j (\rho v_j v_i) + \rho v_j \partial_j v_i\\
\end{align}$$